# Add value from every row in a table and output (Cast JSON string to int)

Tags: mysql, sql, json, substring

I'm querying an SQL database that I have read only access to (Cannot edit tables/create columns etc)

My table contains a column with `JSON` strings that have (Actual strings are much larger, this is just an example) the following syntax

```
{"value":"442","country":"usa"}
```

I would like to add the values contained in the JSON string from each row together and output it as readable, if this is possible?

The values are in the same point of the JSON, as shown above. The values vary in length also, most are 3/4 characters long.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Decide on the database you are using and tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Which database engine you are using is important as the answer will change depending on this.

Comment: Do you actually want proper JSON output, e.g. a JSON array, or do you just want a string concatenation?  Note that you could also handle this in your app layer, e.g. Java, C#, ...

Comment: Sorry about the multiple tags. I've been using both postgresql and mysql, but this would pertain moreso to mysql. I understand SQL is just a query language. I'm moreso just looking for a way to output a sum of all values. Handling this at the app layer would definitely be easier, i'm just wondering how possible it is. Sorry about the ambiguous question, quite new to using SQL.

Comment: Maybe [this documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html) will help?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (for MySQL v5.7+):

```
select sum(json_extract(jsonString, '$.value')) from mytable;
```

An example of this is [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nL2qy9AGeN1CtAH11KpbTb/0).